# Run batch file in autounattend.xml

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, script, automation

I am trying to modify my autounattend.xml file to have it run a batch file on first boot (at the OOBE screen). I tried adding the following in my :

```
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
  <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
    </component>
                <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <CommandLine>C:\Windows\PathtoScriptFile\Script.bat</CommandLine>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
```

Upon running this, I get a message saying "windows could not parse or process unattend answer file" for the oobesystem during my installation.

My autounattend file worked previously up until adding this part. Do I have something incorrectly added?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Windows-International-Core` component opens and closes with no entries. Get rid of it if it's not needed. `FirstLogonCommands` is a child of `OOBE` which belongs to the `Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup` component in this context. Here's how it should look:

```
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
         <OOBE>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                   <CommandLine>C:\Windows\PathtoScriptFile\Script.bat</CommandLine>
                   <Order>1</Order>
                </SynchronousCommand>
               </FirstLogonCommands>
           </OOBE>
    </component>
</settings>
```